# Running unit test of template-scala-parallel-similarproduct

Tags: predictionio

Can anybody help me the way to run the test CooccurenceAlgorithmTest.scala

https://github.com/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct/tree/develop/src/test/scala

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That is a compile time unit test. See this page for how to use sbt to run the test, either as a compile time unit test or in the sbt shell interactively.
http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt